# Server responce received but status code can not be accessed

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, http-status-codes

I am new to asynchronous tasks and trying to create a login UI. When I make a request from the server with valid credentials, everything works fine. When the credentials are incorrect, I use a set of "if" statements to check what the error code of the response is and print the corresponding message. I also have such a message for the case that the response is empty. I can see from the part of the server that all the responses include status codes, even when the credentials are invalid. Furthermore I can see the status code by using checkpoints in my code. But when I try to extract the status code from a response I got for invalid credentials, the only "if" statement that works is the one checking if the response is equal to "". None of the conditions of the other "if" statements are fulfilled even when they should be. Here is my code:

```
public String GET(String u) {
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    String line;
    String jsonString = "";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(u);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + '\n');
        }
        jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return jsonString;
}

public void ProcessResponse(String response) {
    if(response!="") {
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            status = json.getInt("status_code");

            if (status == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Internal server error! Please repeat action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(status == 401) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(status == 400) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bad Request! Please repeat action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(status == 200) {
                try {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("base_url", baseURL);
                    editor.putInt("store_id", json.getInt("store_id"));
                    editor.putInt("pin", json.getInt("pin_number"));
                    editor.putInt("delete_table",json.getInt("delele_table_id"));
                    editor.commit();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), APICall.class);
                intent.putExtra("Action","Main Menu");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Problem encountered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class ServerCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        return GET(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        ProcessResponse(s);
    }
}
```

These functions are called in another part of the code with the execute function as usually done in AsyncTask.

Thank you in advance for your help people!

Edit: The function is called like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "Shared Preferences";
    String url = "";
    String baseURL = "";
    int status = 0;
    JSONObject json = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        CheckBox mode = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.login_development_mode);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText developerURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.base_url);
                EditText store = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.store_id_field);
                EditText pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin_field);

                baseURL = developerURL.getText().toString();

                url = baseURL + "/api/auth/check?store_id="+store.getText().toString()+
                        "&pin_number="+pin.getText().toString();
                ServerCall loginCall = new ServerCall();
                loginCall.execute(url);
            }
        });

       /*more code, including the AsyncTask mentioned above*/
    }
```

Comment: You might want to add how and where this function is called

Comment: `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();`

Comment: @codeMagic: added the rest of the code above.

Comment: @greenapps: I tried to use that but have trouble passing the code from the GET method the Process response method. I will look into that again though. Thank you!
I will try adding status code as a global variable but in the end I am actively trying to avoid many global variables.

Comment: `I will try adding status code as a global variable ` Why would you ? A bad idea. Nobody needs such.

Comment: @greenapps: Exactly. Like I told you, I actively try to avoid using global variables.

Comment: `have trouble passing the code from the GET method the Process response method` ???? What is it that you want? And why would passing an integer be a problem? Dont pass that code! For what?

Comment: As you can see in the code above, I use the status code in the ProcessResponse method to evaluate the "if" statements. The code is carried in this method inside the response string itself but once there I cannot seem to be able to access it. Only the if(response!="") statement is evaluated correctly. 
For example, say the status code the server sent is 500. The expression  if (status == 500) gives false even though it is supposed to give true. And so the code does not print the correct message.

Comment: You are still trying to extract the status code from a json text. That is nonsense. The status/response code is available only as `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()`.

Comment: Can't you just pass that to your processing function? `public void ProcessResponse(String response, int statusCode)`

Comment: @greenapps: You were right! The only way to get the response code if the credentials were invalid was the getResponseCode method. The extraction from the json text works too though, but only in the case that the credentials are valid and you the app gets the response json. That was working before. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @codeMagic: I can not do that because the GET method can only return one argument and it has to be the response itself. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem. Thank you all for responding. I changed the GET and processResponse methods as follows:

```
public String GET(String u) {
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    String line;
    String jsonString = "";
    int code = -1;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(u);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        code = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + '\n');
        }
        jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        status = code;
        return "";
    } finally {
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return jsonString;
}

public void ProcessResponse(String response) {

    if (status == 500) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Internal server error! Please repeat action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(status == 401) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(status == 400) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bad Request! Please repeat action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(status == 200) {
        if(response!="") {
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(response);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("base_url", baseURL);
                editor.putInt("store_id", json.getInt("store_id"));
                editor.putInt("cell_phone", json.getInt("cell_phone"));
                editor.putInt("pin", json.getInt("pin_number"));
                editor.putInt("delete_table", json.getInt("delele_table_id"));
                editor.commit();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), APICall.class);
            intent.putExtra("Action","Main Menu");
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Problem encountered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the way I used the httpURLConnection is the most efficient or if my code is just stupid, but it works, so if anyone has any suggestions to improve it, feel free! Thank you all again!

Comment: No. No good code. You should only examine the response code. As that is the response code from the webserver. If you examine json then you examine a response from your script. They are not comparable. I think you should examine them both if that brings something.

Comment: I do not examine json for the response code any longer. I do not compare them either. I get the code only from the getResponseCode() method and save it in a variable to use it in the ProcessResponse() method, because I cannot pass it otherwise. I only use the response json to extract the information I need for my application, which is saved in SharedPreferences. I know that it's probably not the most elegant solution but it works. I suppose that it would be meaningfull to pass the response code without saving it in a variable, but I can't think of a way yet. Still, as I said, this code works.

Comment: @greenapps: What exactly do you suggest I change?

Comment: `ProcessResponse(String response) `. You are not processing Sting response but int status. Why the hell do you process something that is some kind of global int? Earlier you were suggested to add a parameter. You should do that now. `ProcessResponses(int statusCode, Sting response)`. And do not change a code in that catch block.

Comment: That was the first thing I thought of doing too, but how do I return both these parameters from the  GET method? I would have to create some kind of class to carry them both outside.